# Cleanup asyncio loop after KeyboardInterrupt exception

Tags: python, asynchronous, exception, python-asyncio, future

I'm using *future* in simple chat server to close all pending tasks and close *asyncio loop* when user send "exit" command. In that case it works fine. However when I'm using this method for `KeyboardInterrupt` exception (user press Ctrl+C) I get another exception, and I don't know why.

```
$ python3 chat_server.py
[+] Connection from: ('127.0.0.1', 48532)
[+] Data received: 'asdf\n'
^C[+] Keyboard exception
[+] Cancel all tasks
[+] Stop loop
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "chat_server.py", line 97, in <module>
    loop.run_until_complete(server.wait_closed())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 579, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
concurrent.futures._base.CancelledError
```

What is the proper way to handle this situation?

```py
import sys
import asyncio

class Chat(asyncio.Protocol):
    def __init__(self, loop, queue, fut):
        self.loop = loop
        self.queue = queue
        self.fut = fut

    def connection_made(self, transport):
        print('[+] Connection from:', transport.get_extra_info('peername'))
        self.transport = transport
        self.loop.create_task(self._wait_for_stdin_data())

    def data_received(self, data):
        message = data.decode()
        print('[+] Data received: {!r}'.format(message))
        if message.strip() == "exit":
            self.fut.set_result(True)

    def _send_reply(self, reply):
        print('[+] Data send: {!r}'.format(reply))
        self.transport.write(reply.encode())
        self.loop.create_task(self._wait_for_stdin_data())

    async def _wait_for_stdin_data(self):
        reply = await self.queue.get()
        self._send_reply(reply)

def got_stdin_data(queue):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.create_task(queue.put(sys.stdin.readline()))

def cancel_all_task(result=None):
    print('[+] Cancel all tasks')
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    for task in asyncio.Task.all_tasks():
        task.cancel()
    loop.create_task(stop_loop())

async def stop_loop():
    print('[+] Stop loop')
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.stop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    queue = asyncio.Queue()
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    loop.add_reader(sys.stdin, got_stdin_data, queue)
    fut = loop.create_future()
    fut.add_done_callback(cancel_all_task)
    coro = loop.create_server(lambda: Chat(loop, queue, fut), '127.0.0.1', 7777)
    server = loop.run_until_complete(coro)

    try:
        loop.run_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('[+] Keyboard exception')
        fut.set_result(True)

    server.close()
    loop.run_until_complete(server.wait_closed())
    loop.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

After `fut.set_result(True)` `server.wait_closed()` will be cancelled. I think more appropriate is:

```
    try:
        loop.run_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('[+] Keyboard exception')
        # fut.set_result(True)

    server.close()
    loop.run_until_complete(server.wait_closed())
    fut.set_result(True)
    loop.run_forever()
    loop.close()
```

Comment: This help in case of `KeyboardInterrupt` exception, but break "exit" command handling.